# React Native - How to Map Readable Array from React Native to Native Module in Android)?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have a code in react native. I use it to pass array to native module, and I want to handle it on native module,

Example of `ReadableArray`:

```
{"AuditScheduleDetailID":5525,"AuditAnswerId":33,"LocalFindingID":1,"LocalMediaID":1,"ExtFiles":"jpg"}
```

I want to get each value of key inside - how can I do that?

I've tried [this article](https://medium.com/shoutem/ways-to-pass-objects-between-native-and-javascript-in-react-native-c3dcae7bf4f5) but I dont really understand it.

I just hardcoded it for now like this :

```
@ReactMethod
public void insert(ReadableArray name, String file) {
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getReactApplicationContext());
    String a = "path to file";
    for(int i=0 ; i<name.size(); i++){
    //expected result
    int audit  = 5525 //from AuditScheduleDetailID value
    int answer = 33 // from AuditAnswerId value
    int finding = 1 // from LocalFindingID value
    int media = 1 // from LocalMediaID value
    String exten = "jpg" // from ExtFiles value
    db.addContact(new Contact(audit, answer, finding, media, exten));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get each `value` from readablearray `key`?

Answer (score 4):

On javascript you call this method just passing as object

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

NativeModules.<<ModuleName>>.insert({"AuditScheduleDetailID":5525,"AuditAnswerId":33,"LocalFindingID":1,"LocalMediaID":1,"ExtFiles":"jpg"}, <<fileName>>);
```

Modify your react method to accept `ReadableMap` instead of `ReadableArray`

```
@ReactMethod
public void insert(ReadableMap readableMap, String file) {
  String auditScheduleDetailID = readableMap.getString("AuditScheduleDetailID");
  String auditAnswerId = readableMap.getString("AuditAnswerId");
  String localFindingID = readableMap.getString("LocalFindingID");
  String localMediaID = readableMap.getString("LocalMediaID");
  String extFiles = readableMap.getString("ExtFiles");
  //your logic
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is what you need but,

For `React Native >=0.62`, you can try this:

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;

@ReactMethod
public void test(Callback callback) {
    WritableMap map = Arguments.createMap();

    map.putString("yourKey", "yourValue");

    callback.invoke(map);
}
```